# How do I prefix elements in an array with a $ symbol, using regex and -replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking to prefix all elements in an array with a dollar symbol. Example:

```
$array = "group1","group2"
```

Needs to become:

```
$group1
$group2
```

I know this could be done with a loop command and constructing a new array but I know it must be possible with a one liner and some Regex.

I've been working along the lines of:

```
$array -replace "^(.+)$","replace goes here"
```

I'm aware that `$&` and `$+` will return the match, but no matter what escaping I use to insert the `$`, I can't see to get it to work.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the start of the string (represented by `^`) with `$`:

```powershell
PS > $array = "group1","group2"    
PS > $array -replace "^","$"
$group1
$group2    
PS >
```

Comment: Urgh, so simple! Amazing, thank you :) Will mark as the answer after 10 minutes have passed.